# Locate linking location used by visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, linker, fortran

This seems like it would be a common question, but I can't seem to find an answer:

Is there a way to locate the specific library that VS uses to link a particular function at link time?

I'm using Visual studio to build a multi-project solution. 
I have a Solution (The Library solution) that generates a bunch of .libs  that are used across multiple programs. One of these libs is generated from Fortran code (Intel Fortran 77 compiler) enforcing UPPERCASE names.

I statically link these libraries into the solution that I build my application in (which happens to be in C++, with the appropriate "extern C"s and prototypes.

The issue I have, is that I can delete the library that generates a particular function, and my program happily compiles (okay fine) and links (what the crap!). So I go to every library in Linker->Input->Additional dependencies, and do an objdump looking for the function (well subroutine in fortran) name, and it doesn't come up. I do the same thing for all Project dependencies, and still no dice.

If I go and change the libraries (and all function calls and prototypes) to something random (like myFunction12345) and recompile and link, everything works as I would expect, so clearly something is getting linked in that I can't find.

fwiw my function name is AIR

I'm less interested in solving my particular problem as I am in learning how to figure out what LIBs are being used by VS at link time. Addidionally, I'd love to know if there is some linker flag that can be thrown to warn, or error out if there are multiply defined objects at link time.

any ideas?

Comment: When you say your program compiles OK, I assume you do mean that there is a C++ program with a main and not that the library compiles OK.  Also, are we talking about static libs or DLLs?

Comment: If the compiler does UPPERCASE names to Fortran symbols, it is very weird and not common.  Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @CUP: Well, both the library and the C++ program (which contains main) compile. the library compiles to a .lib and the C++ program compiles and links. The libraries are .lib (statically linked) libraries not DLLs

Comment: @VladimirF we enforce UPPERCASE as a compiler option in the Intel Fortran 77 compiler for this particular library. There is a historical reason for why we do this, but functionally, it is not any diffent than compiling the default way (to lower case). Typically fortran is case invariant, so UPPERCASE or LOWERCASE really doesn't matter until you go to link. When we call the subroutines from C or C++, we do match case. I would just compile to lowercase to test, but it would require quite a bit of code re-write on the C/C++ side, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I should add that I'm less interested in the solving the issues with my particular problem, as I am with finding a tool or process that would allow me to identify conflicts at link time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add /verbose to the linker command line additional options.  In the resulting output, look for lines such "Found _AIR in xxxx".  Surrounding lines should give a pretty clear indication of what's going on.

You may have a library with the same name being pulled in from the library search path ahead of your intended library, or perhaps the relevant symbol is also defined in a default library.

Comment: Alternatively Linker/General/Show Progress, which does the same thing.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! It seems so obvious now.